# Hide text only on first login

Tags: angular

I have 3 pages on my website.

**The first page** -> contains 3 fields (name, phoneNumber, email)

The user enters the informations

[image]

Then, there is a second page with 3 fields (address, zipCode, City)

[image]

There is a title **"first connection"**, if the user is connected several times on the site, I would like to hide this title. So, we will have this:

[image]

And finally the last page

[image]

How Could I solve this problem? I have to use `Route Guards` ?
https://juristr.com/blog/2018/11/better-route-guard-redirects

This second page is a problem for me...

```
<!-- Second page : Start -->
<div class="container" *ngIf="addressComplete">
  <div class="title" style="color: blue; font-size: 25px; text-align:center;"> First connection</div>
  <div class="one">
    <input type="text"
           class="input"
           placeholder="Address">
  </div>
  <div class="two">
    <input type="text"
           class="input"
           placeholder="Zip Code">
  </div>
  <div class="three">
    <input type="text"
           class="input"
           placeholder="City / State">
  </div>
  <div class="four">
    <button class="submit" (click)="addressSubmit()">Submit</button>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- Second page : End -->
```

How could I hide this title in my component.ts ?

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { UserInfo } from '../user-info';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-sign-up',
  templateUrl: './sign-up.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./sign-up.component.css']
})
export class SignUpComponent implements OnInit {
  personalInfoComplete = true;
  addressComplete = false;
  creditCardComplete = false;
  completedOrder = false;

  stepOne = false;
  stepTwo = false;
  stepThree = false;

  customer = false;

  customerInformation = [];

  fruite = ['apple', 'orange'];

  userInfoArray: UserInfo;

  name;

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log('Fruite' + this.fruite.push('banana'));
    console.log(this.fruite);
  }

  personalInfoSubmit() {
    this.personalInfoComplete = false;
    this.addressComplete = true;
    this.stepOne = true;
    this.customer = true;

    console.log('Your Info ' + this.name.userInfoArray);
  }

  addressSubmit() {
    this.addressComplete = false;
    this.creditCardComplete = true;
    this.stepTwo = true;
  }

  creditCardSubmit() {
    this.creditCardComplete = false;
    this.completedOrder = true;
    this.stepThree = true;
  }
}
```

If you are interested here is my code [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/single-page-form-step-by-step-completion-yvyvfb?file=app/sign-up/sign-up.component.ts)

Comment: How do you want to detect first login without any user data?

Comment: @Alireza Ahmadi: by placing a cookie?

Comment: Or local Storage but note that these solution don't guarantee 100%, because user can remove localStorage data

Comment: @Alireza Ahmadi: Ah ok thank you, you don't know a tutorial for beginners?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

Comment: @Alireza Ahmadi: Thank you, it works ! [Url](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-zrtepo?file=src/app/sign-up/sign-up.component.ts) You have more experience, do you not recommend this practice?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what exactly you mean by "connected to the site", but I think you will have to place a cookie onto your site to track if a particular user already visited your site. Then you could use a simple boolean to hide or show the title.

As a site node, you could improve cour code drastically by using angular forms. It is really easy and has powerful validation and saves you a lot of code. Hope I could help you.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation, it's exactly what I want to do...